# PHP Curl API GET request with bearer token for LinkedIn API. Curl setup call

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api, bearer-token

As the title says I'm having a bit of trouble when I'm trying to GET information from the LinkedIn API V2 using the url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams)'

I've already got the necessary access token and when used through Postman, I receive the requested data just fine. But from the application I'm receiving the Error Response = "Empty OAuth2 access token" or 'java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 68'

My guess is that I'm not setting up the API call correctly, and hope you guys are able to help me out?

```
$curl = curl_init(); //CURL version: 7.29, PHP version: 7.4.26

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams)',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('content-type: application/json', "Accept: application/json",
                "Authorization: Bearer {$accessBearerToken}"),
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Not sure what the point of `content-type: application/json` is, for a request that doesn't have any body content to begin with. Have you verified `"Authorization: Bearer {$accessBearerToken}"` actually got substituted with a proper value? Also, I'd try and properly URL encode the content of your query string parameter there - postman might do that automatically, but cURL usually doesn't.

Comment: You are right about the content-type. It's removed. 

Yes I've verified the substitution and it look just perfect. 
Right now I'm encoding the headers with rawURLEncode() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) 

I've tried URL encoding the parameter of the query string using the rawURLEncode(), but unfortunately the response is the same: "Empty OAuth2 access token"

Comment: What happens when you let postman create the PHP cURL code for you, does that look significantly different from what you have above?

Comment: Awsome feature! Wasn't aware of that feature! 

It is actually the same as postman except from the useragent and timeout value and it WORKS! 

Thanks alot guys! I owe you a bottle!